# Setting FontFamily for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-styles, android-fonts

I have this in my styles:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
....
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_extralight</item>
....
    </style>
```

I have many TextViews in many XML files in my app. I want the TextViews to have fontFamily montserrat_extralight . But it seems this is so sophisticated demand Android can't do.

I know that if I inherit my activity from AppCompatActivity, then fontFamily works. But I also have many FragmentActivities in my code.

I also read somewhere that rewriting "TextView" to "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView" helps. But I have no idea what android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView means and I would like to use just "TextView" tag in my XMLs.

So, in year 2020, is it possible to set fontFamily for TextViews in Android?

EDIT: This is my test application. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i_rYPHmJ_XeR8Rajo-fgNYalhCoqyiHP/view?usp=sharing Impossible to set fontFamily When I change e.g.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

to

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

fontFamily works. But my activity have to be FragmentActivity.

Comment: It was possible in previous years as well. Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml and make sure to include the font in the relevant folder

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm glad to see it can be done. So I have res/font/montserrat_extralight_regular.ttf, then I created new Font resource file called montserrat_extralight in res/font folder as described in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml and added <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/montserrat_extralight</item> to my AppTheme styles.xml. And voila - it changed the font for some views in my app (e.g. AppCompatButtons) but still TextViews has some default font.

Comment: Do you have any attributes relating to text appearance in your textviews? they might be overriding your App Theme style

Comment: AppTheme style is the only place where I set fontFamily attribute for anything. I also tried to set fontFamily attribute for one of my TextView's styles and also directly inside TextView tag. Nothing works.

Comment: Try removing the _android:_ before the fontFamily and see if that makes a difference: <item name="fontFamily">@font/montserrat_extralight</item>.

Comment: No difference. BTW, I edited my question and attached test application where you can see that fontFamily for TextView doesnt work.

Comment: _montserrat_extralight_ is an _.xml_ file not a _.ttf_. I tried the other two _.ttf_ files that you have in the _font_ folder and they work fine for me. I even added another font (Ubuntu-R) and that worked fine as well

Comment: I followed instructions https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml , they create xml file for fonts. OK, I removed montserrat_extralight.xml and I used android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_extralight_regular". Still no luck. Can you please zip your project with your modifications and share it with me?

Comment: The only thing I did was to use the name of the .ttf fonts that you already had in there on the textview of your main activity and it worked.

Comment: My application is intended to be run on Lenovo Tab E8 tablet (Android 7). If I load it on my phone Xiaomi Mi 9T (Android 10) then it works. Any explanation why it doesn't work on Lenovo Tab E8?

Answer (score 0):

Create **font** folder in **res** directory and keep your fonts in **font** folder.

Example - 
**roboto_slab_regular.ttf** in font folder.

Use below code in your **TextView**

```
 <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     auto:fontFamily="@font/roboto_slab_regular" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work for my app. Is my gradle configuration bad or what should I change to be able to use fontFamily for my TextViews?

Comment: once you have added the font in your project you can use _android:fontFamily_. Not sure how you define _auto_ in your example.

Comment: What do you mean by "auto"?

Comment: Where should I add this. Anywhere I place it turns grey (Namespace declaration is never used)...

Comment: You have to put into root view as attribute

Comment: OK, I added it to my root layout. Then added auto:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_extralight_regular" to my TextView. Still, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please see my initial post. I attached there my test project.